# Display tag excerpt tooltips when editing a question

Tags: script, editing, tag-wiki

There's a [25-score question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/display-tag-excerpt-tooltips-when-editing-a-question) with the same title requesting this feature.

The obvious solution: create a userscript to do it. :)

[image: showing the excerpt while hovering over tag in edit window]

You can install the script by clicking [here](https://gist.github.com/Scimonster/02cd5e1e901c19ab6ec3/raw/3f0773de252c7eff9b325b11ef3e38edc0e043ef/tagsWhileEditing.user.js).

Comment: Somehow this seems to be broken recently. No errors appear for me in console, so I don't really know what the problem is.